# Database table design issue (simple)

Tags: mysql

I am a bit indecisive about a certain database table structure, here is the scenario:

I have an "invoices" table, and an invoice can be for a "product" or for a "service" (products are in a table, and services in a separate table).

What is the best way to link an invoice to either of those, but also allow adding more options? If it was an invoice for only a product, the table design would be:

```
id, product_id, amount
```

But what is the best way for this scenario? I was thinking something like:

```
id, source_id, invoice_type (product or service), amount
```

But I thought that it might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there aren't any differences between `product` and `service` invoices, just use one table with an `invoice_type` field.

---

After reading your entire question, what you listed at the end is right.  What you should look at is examples of a [subclass](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=subclass.php) and superclass.

Basically, all your fields that are the same can be grouped into one table, then fields that only pertain to a specific type of service can be grouped into its own table.  Instead of having 1 or 2 tables, you'll end up with a max of 3 (a superclass and 2 subclasses where needed), and they will be more normalized.

---

Given your example *(Note: this is just an example)*:

- **Superclass:Invoice**

  ```
  id, invoice_type (product or service), amount, invoice_dt, customer_paid
  ```
- **Subclass:Product**

  ```
  invoice_id, msrp, cost, purchase_dt
  ```
- **Subclass:Services**

  ```
  invoice_id, duration, extraneous_cost, start_dt, end_dt
  ```

Comment: +1  After all if you later start to find things that are specific to service invoices, say a "special service tax" you can add a invoice_service_detail tableor something that has the invoice_id and then other fields as desired (plus its own ID of course).

Comment: (after updates) yes vol7ron's approach is more flexible, extensible, DRyer, etc.  Which approach to take - 1 extra table explicitly tables will depend on your need/desire. If it's part of an ORM web-based system you could one table but separate objects that derive from it.

Comment: yea, I would be thinking  the same but the data is exactly the same, the only difference is the type...so 1 table seemed like a better option..but I was then thinking if I wanted to link the table to a parent table using foreign keys, I cannot do that (if I'm not mistaken)...since I'm using the same index which in different cases can refer to different tables...

Comment: @roynaufal: it's important to plan for the future, since things change.  I'm not sure how `things are the same`, but I'd say if you don't need the subclass tables, you aren't required to use them, but do capture the `invoice_type` on the main table, in case you want to use them in the future. You don't have to use `product` or `service`, a simple `P` or `S` could be fine, or if you want you can make that a FK to another table that is a bunch of different types of products/services.

Answer (score 1):

An Invoice can refer to many Products or Services.

A Product can appear on many Invoices, because lots of people can purchase the same Product.

But what about Service?  If you treat that the same as a Product, then you need a many-to-many table between the two.

I'd debate whether or not a parent table for both Product and Service is needed.  Be sure that there's truly an important distinction between the two in your model.

Personally, I think a single table for both is simpler.  I'd go with that until I had a clear reason for distinguishing between them.

Comment: I do agree, but I wanted to implementing a foreign key, but in that case it becomes impossible (I think?) since I have the same index, each time referring to a different parent table...what would you suggest in that case?

Comment: Nope, not impossible.  You need a parent table with an id primary key and a type column.  The PRODUCT and SERVICE tables will have a foreign key to their respective parent records.